# How to generate a repeated parabola signal with Python

Tags: python, signal-processing

I need to plot a repeated signal of the function f(x) = x^2
with a period of 2, between -1 and 1, from an array, plotted from -10 to 10.
Is there a more elegant way to do this (to hand in to my professor :), like a scipy-equivalent to the matlab function GENSIG() for example?

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t3 = np.linspace(-1,1,1000)
x3 = t3**2
x = np.array_split(x3,2)[1]

for i in range(9):
  x = np.concatenate((x, x3))
x = np.concatenate((x,np.array_split(x3,2)[0]))

t = np.linspace(-10,10,10000)
plt.plot(t, x, linewidth=1, color='blue')
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iw6s0.png)

Comment: What code is there?

Comment: I have added the code, the way I solved it, and I changed the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a repeating signal, an elegant way to do so is to make `t3` be an array that repeats from -1 to 1:

```
t = np.linspace(-10,10,10000)
t_mod = t % 2 - 1
y = t_mod**2

plt.plot(t, y, linewidth=1, color='blue')
plt.show()
```

I have taken the liberty to modify your variables a little for clarity. Hope this helps!